# Check the total number of parameters in a PyTorch model

Tags: python, pytorch

How do I count the total number of parameters in a PyTorch model? Something similar to `model.count_params()` in Keras.

Comment: do `num_params: int = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)` for trainable number of params

Answer (score 312, accepted):

PyTorch doesn't have a function to calculate the total number of parameters as Keras does, but it's possible to sum the number of elements for every parameter group:

```
pytorch_total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
```

If you want to calculate only the *trainable* parameters:

```
pytorch_total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
```

---

*Answer inspired by [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-check-the-number-of-parameters-of-a-model/4325/9) on PyTorch Forums*.

Answer (score 85):

To get the parameter count of each layer like Keras, PyTorch has [`model.named_parameters()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_parameters) that returns an iterator over both the parameter name and the parameter itself. Example:

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def count_parameters(model):
    table = PrettyTable(["Modules", "Parameters"])
    total_params = 0
    for name, parameter in model.named_parameters():
        if not parameter.requires_grad:
            continue
        params = parameter.numel()
        table.add_row([name, params])
        total_params += params
    print(table)
    print(f"Total Trainable Params: {total_params}")
    return total_params
    
count_parameters(net)
```

Example output:

```
+-------------------+------------+
|      Modules      | Parameters |
+-------------------+------------+
| embeddings.weight |   922866   |
|    conv1.weight   |  1048576   |
|     conv1.bias    |    1024    |
|     bn1.weight    |    1024    |
|      bn1.bias     |    1024    |
|    conv2.weight   |  2097152   |
|     conv2.bias    |    1024    |
|     bn2.weight    |    1024    |
|      bn2.bias     |    1024    |
|    conv3.weight   |  2097152   |
|     conv3.bias    |    1024    |
|     bn3.weight    |    1024    |
|      bn3.bias     |    1024    |
|    lin1.weight    |  50331648  |
|     lin1.bias     |    512     |
|    lin2.weight    |   265728   |
|     lin2.bias     |    519     |
+-------------------+------------+
Total Trainable Params: 56773369
```

Answer (score 18):

To avoid double counting shared parameters, use [`torch.Tensor.data_ptr`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.data_ptr). E.g.:

```py
sum(dict((p.data_ptr(), p.numel()) for p in model.parameters()).values())
```

Here's a more verbose implementation that can optionally filter out non-trainable parameters:

```py
def numel(m: torch.nn.Module, only_trainable: bool = False):
    """
    Returns the total number of parameters used by `m` (only counting
    shared parameters once); if `only_trainable` is True, then only
    includes parameters with `requires_grad = True`
    """
    parameters = list(m.parameters())
    if only_trainable:
        parameters = [p for p in parameters if p.requires_grad]
    unique = {p.data_ptr(): p for p in parameters}.values()
    return sum(p.numel() for p in unique)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `torchsummary` to do the same thing. It's just two lines of code.

```
from torchsummary import summary

print(summary(model, (input_shape)))
```

Comment: That project appears to be abandoned, as of 2023, there is an updated fork here: https://github.com/TylerYep/torchinfo

Answer (score 8):

If you want to calculate the number of weights and biases in each layer without instantiating the model, you can simply load the raw file and iterate over the resulting `collections.OrderedDict` like so:

```py
import torch


tensor_dict = torch.load('model.dat', map_location='cpu') # OrderedDict
tensor_list = list(tensor_dict.items())
for layer_tensor_name, tensor in tensor_list:
    print('Layer {}: {} elements'.format(layer_tensor_name, torch.numel(tensor)))
```

You'll get something like

```
conv1.weight: 312
conv1.bias: 26
batch_norm1.weight: 26
batch_norm1.bias: 26
batch_norm1.running_mean: 26
batch_norm1.running_var: 26
conv2.weight: 2340
conv2.bias: 10
batch_norm2.weight: 10
batch_norm2.bias: 10
batch_norm2.running_mean: 10
batch_norm2.running_var: 10
fcs.layers.0.weight: 135200
fcs.layers.0.bias: 260
fcs.layers.1.weight: 33800
fcs.layers.1.bias: 130
fcs.batch_norm_layers.0.weight: 260
fcs.batch_norm_layers.0.bias: 260
fcs.batch_norm_layers.0.running_mean: 260
fcs.batch_norm_layers.0.running_var: 260
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution with respect

```
def model_summary(model):
  print("model_summary")
  print()
  print("Layer_name"+"\t"*7+"Number of Parameters")
  print("="*100)
  model_parameters = [layer for layer in model.parameters() if layer.requires_grad]
  layer_name = [child for child in model.children()]
  j = 0
  total_params = 0
  print("\t"*10)
  for i in layer_name:
    print()
    param = 0
    try:
      bias = (i.bias is not None)
    except:
      bias = False  
    if not bias:
      param =model_parameters[j].numel()+model_parameters[j+1].numel()
      j = j+2
    else:
      param =model_parameters[j].numel()
      j = j+1
    print(str(i)+"\t"*3+str(param))
    total_params+=param
  print("="*100)
  print(f"Total Params:{total_params}")       

model_summary(net)
```

This would give output similar to below

```
model_summary

Layer_name                          Number of Parameters
====================================================================================================

Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))             60
Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))            880
Linear(in_features=576, out_features=120, bias=True)        69240
Linear(in_features=120, out_features=84, bias=True)         10164
Linear(in_features=84, out_features=10, bias=True)          850
====================================================================================================
Total Params:81194
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin utility function to convert an iterable of tensors into a tensor: [`torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector.html), then combine with [`torch.numel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.numel.html):

```
torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(model.parameters()).numel()
```

Or shorter with a named import (`from torch.nn.utils import parameters_to_vector`):

```
parameters_to_vector(model.parameters()).numel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Final answer you can plug in:

```
def count_number_of_parameters(model: nn.Module, only_trainable: bool = True) -> int:
    """
    Counts the number of trainable params. If all params, specify only_trainable = False.

    Ref:
        - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-check-the-number-of-parameters-of-a-model/4325/9?u=brando_miranda
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201236/check-the-total-number-of-parameters-in-a-pytorch-model/62764464#62764464
    :return:
    """
    if only_trainable:
        num_params: int = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
    else:  # counts trainable and none-traibale
        num_params: int = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p)
    assert num_params > 0, f'Err: {num_params=}'
    return int(num_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers fully address if different parameters share memory, including the answers that use `numel`, `PrettyTable` and `.data_ptr`. @teichert gave a great answer that handles the case where there are two different parameters that point to the **exact same** tensor. But what if one parameter is a slice of another? Though they would share some memory, using`.data_ptr()` naively would come up with [different results](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-way-to-check-if-two-tensors-have-the-same-base/44310/2?u=timgianitsos) - thus there would still be overcounting using his approach.

To be thorough, you need to ensure that *none* of the entries in *any* of the tensors point to the same thing. This can be accomplished by using set-comprehensions:

Include non-trainable parameters:

```py
len({e.data_ptr() for p in model.parameters() for e in p.view(-1)})
```

Ignore non-trainable parameters:

```py
len({e.data_ptr() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad for e in p.view(-1)})
```

---

If tensors can share memory, how about counting the number of unique tensors? This sounds like a tricky interview problem, but it's easy with the UnionFind data structure! If you don't want to `pip install` it, just copy [this file](https://gist.github.com/timgianitsos/0878a0b241cb5d0ad8b16ebc2b14322a) verbatim as a drop in replacement.

Pass your model into this function, and it will not overcount if there is any memory sharing *even if* some parameters are slices of others.

```py
def num_parameters(model, show_only_trainable):
    from UnionFind import UnionFind
    u = UnionFind()
    for p in model.parameters():
        if not show_only_trainable or p.requires_grad:
            u.union(*[e.data_ptr() for e in p.view(-1)])
    print(f'Number of parameters: {len(u)}')
    print(f'Number of tensors: {u.num_connected_components}')
```

---

This code demonstrates the problem with using the other techniques and how using the above function fixes it.

```py
>>> import torch.nn as nn
>>> import torch
>>> torch.manual_seed(0)
>>> 
>>> # This layer is not trainable
>>> frozen_layer = nn.Linear(out_features=3, in_features=4, bias=False)
>>> for p in frozen_layer.parameters():
...     p.requires_grad = False
... 
>>> 
>>> # There are 4*2 + 3*4 = 20 total parameters
>>> # There are 4*2 = 8 trainable parameters
>>> model = nn.Sequential(
...     nn.Linear(out_features=4, in_features=2, bias=False),
...     nn.ReLU(),
...     frozen_layer,
...     nn.Sigmoid()
... )
>>> 
>>> # Parameters seem properly accounted for so far
>>> sum(dict((p.data_ptr(), p.numel()) for p in model.parameters()).values())
20
>>> sum(dict((p.data_ptr(), p.numel()) for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad).values())
8
>>> 
>>> # Add a new Parameter that is an arbitrary slice of an existing Parameter.
>>> # NOTE that slice syntax `[]` and wrapping with `nn.Parameter()` do
>>> # NOT copy the data, but merely point to part of existing tensor.
>>> model.newparam = nn.Parameter(next(model.parameters())[0:2, 1:2])
>>> 
>>> params = list(model.parameters())
>>> 
>>> # Notice that both appear the same. Do they share memory?
>>> # `params[0]` is `model.newparam`. `params[1]` is tensor that `params[0]` was sliced from.
>>> 
>>> params[0]
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.4683],
        [ 0.0262]], requires_grad=True)
>>> 
>>> params[1][0:2, 1:2]
tensor([[-0.4683],
        [ 0.0262]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
>>> 
>>> with torch.no_grad():
...     params[0][0, 0] = 1.2345
... 
>>> 
>>> # Both have changed, proving that they DO share memory.
>>> 
>>> params[0]
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.2345],
        [0.0262]], requires_grad=True)
>>> 
>>> params[1][0:2, 1:2]
tensor([[1.2345],
        [0.0262]], grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
>>> 
>>> # WRONG - the number of parameters "appears" to have increased by 2 (because of `model.newparam`).
>>> sum(dict((p.data_ptr(), p.numel()) for p in model.parameters()).values())
22
>>> sum(dict((p.data_ptr(), p.numel()) for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad).values())
10
>>> 
>>> # CORRECT - this discounts all shared parameters
>>> len({e.data_ptr() for p in model.parameters() for e in p.view(-1)})
20
>>> len({e.data_ptr() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad for e in p.view(-1)})
8
>>> 
>>> # To count unique tensors, we can use this function.
>>> # It utilizes the UnionFind data structure which can be dropped in directly from here:
>>> # https://gist.github.com/timgianitsos/0878a0b241cb5d0ad8b16ebc2b14322a
>>> def num_parameters(model, show_only_trainable):
...     from UnionFind import UnionFind
...     u = UnionFind()
...     for p in model.parameters():
...         if not show_only_trainable or p.requires_grad:
...             u.union(*[e.data_ptr() for e in p.view(-1)])
...     print(f'Number of parameters: {len(u)}')
...     print(f'Number of tensors: {u.num_connected_components}')
... 
>>> 
>>> # Notice that the problem has been fixed
>>> num_parameters(model, show_only_trainable=False)
Number of parameters: 20
Number of tensors: 2
>>> num_parameters(model, show_only_trainable=True)
Number of parameters: 8
Number of tensors: 1
```

Bear in mind that using my `num_parameters()` function takes longer to run than the other solutions since it has to loop over all the entries in all the tensors - about 2 minutes on my Mac's CPU for a [22 million parameter model](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2). It can be made much faster if you utilize the fact that the data pointers for consecutive memory addresses differ by the same constant amount (e.g. 4 bytes if the tensor is `torch.float32`). But this requires taking the tensors' `dtype` and `stride` into account which is probably overkill if you are willing to wait a few minutes on anything larger than 20 million parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [torchinfo](https://github.com/tyleryep/torchinfo) library.

To see all the information:

```py
from torchinfo import summary
print(summary(model, (batch_size, *input_shape)))
```

Example of getting the number of trainable parameters:

```py
n_param = summary(nn.Linear(10, 1)).trainable_params
```

Answer (score -1):

As [@fábio-perez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604734/f%C3%A1bio-perez) mentioned, there is no such built-in function in PyTorch.

However, I found this to be a compact and neat way of achieving the same result:

```python
num_of_parameters = sum(map(torch.numel, model.parameters()))
```