# Training yolov5 models with 4K images

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, yolov5

Did anyone ever trained a model with 4K images? I mean, yolov5 has a parameter (img-size) that can be set to 3840 and other parameter (rect) that put the image in rectangular form.
I know it is possible, but I need to know what graphic card is usually used in this scenario. I have a RTX 3060 with 12GB VRAM and I can't train as the computer hangs and I get a cuda memory error. Also, when making inference with 4K images what is a recommended graphic card to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the activation for each layer.

For CNN it is the matrix dimension of that layer:

```
activation(n) = image_width * image_height * image_num_channels
```

For Dence Layer it is the number of output:

```
activation(n) = outputs(n)
```

Calculate the memory required for a model:

```
memory_required = (weights + biases * 3 + activations * 2 * batch_size) * 4
```

This output is in bytes. Conver it to GB by dividing by 1024^2.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the weights, biases, activations where can I see them?

Comment: That depends on which framework you are using. Tensorflow or PyTorch.

Comment: This is for the yolov5 pytorch version.

Comment: Try this code:
import torch


tensor_dict = torch.load('model.dat', map_location='cpu') # OrderedDict
tensor_list = list(tensor_dict.items())
for layer_tensor_name, tensor in tensor_list:
    print('Layer {}: {} elements'.format(layer_tensor_name, torch.numel(tensor)))

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525518/14873515

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll see that

Comment: The activation in the last formula is the sum of all the activation layers? If I use a 4K image does it mean the activation layer is 3840*2160*3?