# How many neurons (units) are there in the BERT model?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model, large-language-model

How to estimate the number of neurons (units) in the BERT model?
**Note** this is different from the number of model parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check the total number of parameters in a PyTorch model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201236/check-the-total-number-of-parameters-in-a-pytorch-model)

Comment: Clearly not. The number of parameters basically corresponds to the neuron (units) weights. For example, in a simple linear layer with three input units and two output units (consequently five units or neurons), we have 3x5 parameters without counting the biases.

Comment: Work backwards from the no. of parameters, e.g. https://www.beren.io/2022-08-06-The-scale-of-the-brain-vs-machine-learning/. Roughly 1000 parameters: 1 neuron.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which field you come from the "neurons" definition might differ.

In general, people in computer science conflates `num_neurons = num_parameters`. But this might not be the case if one is interested in more neurological/biological perspective.

#### Q: Why do computer scientist care about no. of parameters not neurons?

Because they determine the effectiveness of the model in terms of FLOPs, see https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/jJApGWG95495pYM7C/how-to-measure-flop-s-for-neural-networks-empirically

#### Q: How many neurons is one parameter, or vice versa?

For that we can only estimate, naively, we can treat it as 1 neuron = 1000 parameters

**Reference:** https://www.beren.io/2022-08-06-The-scale-of-the-brain-vs-machine-learning/

#### Q: How many neurons BERT have?

Depends on which flavor of BERT you are referring to.

Using snippets from [Check the total number of parameters in a PyTorch model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201236/check-the-total-number-of-parameters-in-a-pytorch-model)

```
from transformers import AutoModel
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
```

[out]:

```
108310272
```

So working backwards, given 1000:1 ratio, 108,310,272 parameters -> 0.1M neurons.